# Can't append elements from firestore to an array before view loads; Swift

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I have a Picker View in my app and want it to display documents from a collection in Firestore.  I know my Picker View works but I can't get the elements from firestore to append before the view loads, so they don't show up in my picker view (or at least that's what I think is the problem).

Here is the relevant code:

```
let db = Firestore.firestore()
let userID = Auth.auth().currentUser!.uid
lazy var pickerData: [String] = [String]()
lazy var pickedSchool = String()

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    self.picker.delegate = self
    self.picker.dataSource = self
    pickerData += ["Select your school"]
    db.collection("schoolsUsing").getDocuments() { (querySnapshot, err) in
        if let err = err {
            print("Error getting documents: \(err)")
        } else {
            for document in querySnapshot!.documents {
                let school = document.data()["school"] as? String
                self.pickerData += [school!]
                print("added " + school!)
            }
        }
    }
    for item in pickerData {
        print(item)
    }
}
```

As you can see I put a few "prints" into the console to better understand what is going on and here is the console:

```
Select your school 
2018-06-25 10:25:32.379608-0400 Student Council App[3092:1552543] TIC Read Status [1:0x0]: 1:57
2018-06-25 10:25:32.525625-0400 Student Council App[3092:1552563] 4.11.0 - [Firebase/Analytics][I-ACS023007] Firebase Analytics v.40100000 started
2018-06-25 10:25:32.526111-0400 Student Council App[3092:1552563] 4.11.0 - [Firebase/Analytics][I-ACS023008] To enable debug logging set the following application argument: -FIRAnalyticsDebugEnabled
2018-06-25 10:25:33.028197-0400 Student Council App[3092:1552540] [MC] System group container for systemgroup.com.apple.configurationprofiles path is /private/var/containers/Shared/SystemGroup/systemgroup.com.apple.configurationprofiles
2018-06-25 10:25:33.030894-0400 Student Council App[3092:1552540] [MC]
Reading from public effective user settings.
added Longmeadow High School
added East Longmeadow High School
```

We can see that "select school" is showing up at the very beginning taking command from the for loop at the end of the viewDidLoad() but the "added school" only shows up at the end of the firebase mumbo-jumbo.  I need when the for loop prints out everything in pickerData at the beginning for it to show the schools too.

Comment: Picker View is much like a Collection or Table View in that you need to send a message to reload the data after adding data to its datastore.

Comment: @cnbecom oh that makes sense, how would I do that and where?

Comment: I would do it whenever new data is added and you want that data shown. Here, it can be in the closure - however, ensure you send the message to reload on the main thread.

Comment: @cnbecom I added a self.picker.reloadAllComponents() after the data is added and it works but it takes a few seconds before it shows up.  Is there a faster way to do this?

Comment: so you are sure the data is fetched and then there is a delay? The fetching itself will cause a delay, hence the need for the closure.

Comment: @cnbecom no I understand the data fetch is causing the delay but I'd rather nothing be shown before it is fetched

Comment: @cnbecom I figured it out now though. Thanks!